# How to set arguments from XCUItest class that are accessible in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to set a variable or dictionary in my XCUITest that will decide which screen to show when the app starts. The variable or dictionary should be accessible in the app delegate is this possible.

Just at the top of my mind I am thinking of something along the lines of , NSDefaults, launchArguments or environment variables. Is it possible to set a variable in XCUItest and access it in the App delegate before the app starts so that the variable can be used to determine which screen to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `launchArguments` in your UI test. I would use it like that:

```
app.launchArguments.append("setupForAbcUITest")
```

and then, you can use it in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("setupForAbcUITest") {
    /// create dictionary or anything you like
}
```

Comment: What is the life cycle of launchArguments, are they like NSDefaults in the sense that does a value last through to the next app launch. Reason is I want to know do I have to delete the launchArgument data before setting new one on app launch

Comment: It is not working like UserDefaults, it will perish after the next relaunch. So if you want to have a permanent value, you should use UserDefaults in that ProcessInfo block.

Comment: Is it possible to pass an object say of type UIViewController to the app delegate rather than send a string

Comment: No, and it is a bad architecture solution.

Comment: I want to notify the app delegate to start a specific view when I run a certain test from my bed tests. My app has over 100 views , is there a way I can do this